# replace word through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I have a wordpress site. Here is [link to site](http://womackpi.com/?portfolios=letters). I want to redirect `www.abc.com/?portfolios=letters` to `www.abc.com/?files=letters`.
I tried editing in code, but din't worked.

Here is htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on


 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^womackpi.com/?portfolio=(.+) womackpi.com/?files=$1 [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteRule ^abc.com/?portfolios=(.+) abc.com/?files=$1 [NC]
```

It works for me!

You will also need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Above the previous statement.

Comment: What I mean, Is did you get redirected to an error page, or what?

Comment: Here is the link [link](http://womackpi.com/?portfolios=letters). nothing happened, it din't get redirected.

Comment: Oh. I don't think I can help you more than that :(

Answer (score 0):

Query strings are not part of the URI that is used to match against the expression in `RewriteRule`..

Try replacing `RewriteRule ^womackpi.com/?portfolio=(.+) womackpi.com/?files=$1 [NC]` with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?womackpi.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)portfolio=(.+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?files=%2  [L]
```

Add an `R` inside the `[L]` brackets if you want to redirect the browser (changing the URL in the address bar).